# I can't load or crawl my Website with Google Search Console or PageSpeedInsights

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, google-search-console, google-pagespeed

When I add my website domain: https://tayninh.gov.vn/, both of Google Search Console and Goolge Pagespeedinsights shown error like:
Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)

At first, I thought my robots.txt is wrong, but Ive checked, there is nothing wrong with it.
Ive tried with Bing, they can crawl and index my website.

Please help me.

Comment: There appears to be a problem with your redirect from http to https. Page Speed Insights tries to access your page on HTTP to check that you have redirected correctly, at this point the site is blocked so the test fails and I would guess that is where your issue lies. Make sure that the http version of the site is available and redirects to the https version and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, currently we use Sharepoint and IIS for this website on Port 443, I dont know if we can fix issue with port 80 or not?

Comment: Been a long time since I have played with IIS but from what i remember you add the http and http://www paths to your bindings and yes, you use port 80 by default. Then I think it is just Your Application -> require SSL in your application. I have no doubt there are loads of answers on stack overflow for that. Let me know if it fixes the issue so I can turn it into an answer that may help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I can access my page on http now (with reverse proxy). But Google still can't access my website: URL is not on Google
This page is not in the index, but not because of an error. See the details below to learn why it wasn't indexed.
Strange!

Comment: That is correct (if I understood you correctly). The http version wasn't accessible so wasn't indexed. You don't actually want http version to index anyway (which is why you redirect it), just one canonical version. Just make sure you set your http -> https redirect up. (and www. to non www. for http as people forget that one!)

Comment: I realized that goolge could not fetch the url or rather our IP. I will close this question and create new one!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has opened a new question as this issue is not what they thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason is our DNS config, but not the website itself. So I will close this question and find correct way to resolve this.